# How to get X,Y position in android?

Tags: android, view, position, ontouchlistener

I am beginner to android and I am asking to make sure.
Is there any possible way to get **fixed X,Y position** for all devices?
I need to get fixed point dimensions where the screen is touched.
From what I read getx, gety is what could be used but the result varies depending on device dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps expand a little more about what you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Well, i want to get the (x,y) point where a user touches the screen say (100,90) , but i want this value to be same for that position (where the user touched) in all devices, meaning it's independent of screen size.

Comment: From what i concluded it is not possible to do so because of screen sizes variations. But I am asking if maybe there is a way I didn't come by when I searched.